# SQL query to retrieve role

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a normalised schema consisting of a User table (with a UserID column and other data columns like FirstName, LastName, etc), a UserRole table (with a UserID and a RoleID columns) and a Role table (with a RoleID column and other data columns like RoleName, RoleDescription, etc).

I am after a result set that consists of all user so essentially something like

`SELECT * FROM Users`

But I would also like to know if each of these users is also an Admin or not without getting into a n+1 scenario. Admin is a role that exists in the Role table. Roles and Users are linked with the UserRole table.

The schema is not flexible so I have to work with what I have so my question is is there a single SQL query that I can run that gives me something along the line of a list of all users with a simple "yes" or "no" if they are an admin?

UPDATE: I would also like to add that a user can belong to multiple roles and I would like to ignore all roles that are not Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has multiple roles and one of the roles is Admin, there should be a "Y" in the isAdmin column. It should be one row per user including those with multiple roles assigned.

```
select  
       u.*,
       case when r.roleid is null then 'N'
            else 'Y'
       end as isAdmin
from user u
left join (select ur.userid, ur.roleid
           from   userrole ur
           join   role rl
           on     ur.roleid = rl.roleid
           where  rl.rolename = 'Admin' ) r
on u.userid = r.userid
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do left joins with the two tables for the Admin role and see if the match exists by checking if right table has that user:

```
select u.*,
    case when ur.UserID is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as isAdmin
from users u
left join UserRole ur 
    on u.UserID = ur.UserID 
left join Role r
    on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID 
    and r.RoleName = 'Admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the users' list with the user is admin or not.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * ,
case r.Role
WHEN 'Admin' THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'NO'
END as ISAdmin
FROM User as u
INNER JOIN UserRole as ur on ur.UserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN Role as r on ur.RoleId = r.id
```

SQLFiddler: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208789/5

Comment: A LEFT OUTER JOIN would be a better choice in case the User has no role.

Comment: ... and if a user has multiple roles this will produce multiple rows for the user rather than a single row with a yes/no status.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*,CASE WHEN B.Role_id  = 1 --Here should be the id of the admin role
THEN 'Yes' ELSE  'No' END AS IsAdmin
FROM Users A
JOIN UserRole B ON A.User_id = B.User_id
JOIN Roles C ON B.Role_Id = C.Role_Id
```